# Estimatefee value not corresponding to actual fee

Tags: json-rpc, transaction-fees, bitcoin-core

When I call `estimatefee 1` in testnet it returns: 0.00044444

Then when I call `sendtoaddress xxxxxx 0,1` (which got the first confirmation within a couple of minutes after sending) I see that the fee included is: 0.00001662 BTC, which is about 27 times smaller that the original estimate.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`estimatefee 1` will return the approx. fee per **kilobyte**.

Because `sendtoaddress` could use multiple of your unspent coins, the size of your transaction is not know until it is created (until the coin selection ran).

Example: Fresh wallet. You did receive 10 times 1 BTC. Now you create a transaction with `sendtoaddress <ard> 9.5`. This will produce a transaction with 10 inputs (your received 10 x 1BTC). Therefor the transaction size is bigger than if you would have received 1 x 10BTC.

At the moment there is no easy way of getting the transaction fee before sending the tx (on RPC level). You could use Bitcoin-Qt (there you will see the fee before sending within the confirmation dialog).

There is a pull request for bitcoin-core that would allow fee calculation before sending the tx: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/6088

Comment: The pull request will provide a great functionality that is missing today from the RPC API, nice work!